# WooCommerce checkout fields validation with JS

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Error: Checkout field First and last name validation accepts numbers in a multi-step form.
First and last names shouldn't accept numbers and show a custom error message and don't allow the Multistep form to continue to the next step if the validation is failed.
Extra info: the multi-step form is made by the flux checkout plugin.
Troubleshooting:
We added the below code in the Function.php child theme:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'ybc_validate_fname_lname', 10, 2);
function ybc_validate_fname_lname( $fields, $errors ){
 
    if ( !ctype_alpha($fields[ 'billing_first_name' ]) || !ctype_alpha($fields[ 'billing_last_name' ])  ){
        $errors->add( 'validation', 'First Name and Last Name should only be letters.' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ybc_javascript_validation' );
function ybc_javascript_validation(){
 
    if( !is_checkout() ) return;
 
    ?> <script>jQuery(function($){
        $('body').on('blur change', '#billing_first_name', function(){
            var formRow = $(this).parents('.form-row');
            if( /\d/.test( $(this).val() ) ) { 
                formRow.addClass('woocommerce-invalid'); 
            } else {
                formRow.addClass('woocommerce-validated');
            }
        });
        $('body').on('blur change', '#billing_last_name', function(){
            var formRow = $(this).parents('.form-row');
            if( /\d/.test( $(this).val() ) ) { 
                formRow.addClass('woocommerce-invalid'); 
            } else {
                formRow.addClass('woocommerce-validated');
            }
        });
        
    });</script> <?php
}
```

Result: the code worked but it didn't show up the correct error message on the above code + it didn't stop the form from moving to the next step when the validation failed.

My website:https://coveti.com/checkout/

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you hook `ybc_validate_fname_lname` function?

Comment: I did update my code, please check it

Comment: `ctype_alpha` function might be returning true all the time so you don't get any error. Debug and test that function.

Comment: I have use,,,preg_match,,, function instead but it is still not working

Comment: Remove if condition and add error without and see if you see the error or not. if you see the error then the issue is with the if condition if not then you must have another issue with a hook.

Comment: I did remove the if condition, still not working. I also used another issue with a hook, it has the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple code works fine(Tested locally), If this code doesn't work then either your hook is executed or you have other conflicts with the theme and plugins.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'ybc_validate_fname_lname', 10, 2 );
function ybc_validate_fname_lname( $fields, $errors ) {
    if ( preg_match( '/\\d/', $fields['billing_first_name'] ) || preg_match( '/\\d/', $fields['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'validation', 'Your first or last name contains a number. Really?' );
    }
}
```